# While reviewing can we get preview output?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

While reviewing I sometimes find good questions that weren't formatted with `markdown` thus someone attempts to improve readability by adding `markdown`. Or sometimes someone reformats code, seeing this only in `markdown` hides whether or not the formatting is useful. Is it already possible to preview the formatted output? if not it would improve my ability to approve or reject edits based on improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are buttons to toggle between rendered output and markdown.  They are located between the review action bar and the post.

[image: preview buttons]

There is an extra button when reviewing reopen votes to see the changes inline.  Why it's not in the suggested edit queue is known only to Tony the Pony, and he's not talking.